# SQL Server syntax to create clustered primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to move a table to a new filegroup. Using [the accepted answer as a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2438060/12597):

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_YourTable
   ON dbo.YourTable(YourClusteringKeyFields)
   WITH DROP_EXISTING
   ON [filegroup_name]
```

i adapt it to my use:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID
   ON dbo.AuditLog(AuditLogID)
   WITH DROP_EXISTING
   ON [TheOtherFileGroup]
```

gives the error:

> Msg 1907, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot recreate index 'PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID'. The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index.

This is, i assume, because `PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID` is

- a clustered index
- a primary key

So i need the syntax to create a primary key clustered index `WITH DROP_EXISTING`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID
   ON dbo.AuditLog(AuditLogID)
   WITH DROP_EXISTING
   ON [TheOtherFileGroup]
```

The logical primary key constraint *is* preserved (though tested in 2012)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditLog
(
AuditLogID int constraint PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID primary key
)


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID
   ON dbo.AuditLog(AuditLogID)
   WITH DROP_EXISTING
   ON [Primary]



SELECT CONSTRAINT_TYPE  /*Returns PRIMARY KEY*/
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK_AuditLog_AuditLogID'
```

Comment: @IanBoyd I don't have 2008 to test. Does it preserve the Primary Key constraint OK on that or is this a new thing for 2012?

Comment: No, it worked fine - the primary key is still the primary key (in SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: @IanBoyd - Good stuff. I saw the other answers and began to doubt it!

Comment: Great! It solved my problem. I needed to move tables to a new filegroup. I thought the only way is to drop FK constrain, then PK constrain, then recreate index, and recreate both constrains back. Your solution is working so nice, and it is beautiful!
Thank you.

Comment: i was having this problem again today. Googling brought me to this question on SO. i went to upvote this useful question - *"You cannot upvote your own post"*  *"Wait, what!?"*

Answer (score 0):

Although not applicable to your particular question, another possibility is that a person may be trying to add columns to the PK in an order other than they were in initially. If you are attempting to re-create the index from info in `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns`, make sure you are building based on the order of `sys.index_columns.key_ordinal`