# How can I make data fall in newly created ndf file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very big database and its `.MDF` and `.LDF` files are stored on different drives (say drive D and E); now the D drive which has the `.MDF` file is running out of space so I created a new `.NDF` file on another new drive (say drive H), but after I run some insert/update scripts, it still shows there is no space on the D drive. How do I make the newly created `.NDF` to make use of modified data to get allocate in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to change the table's filegroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928315/efficient-way-to-change-the-tables-filegroup)

Answer (score 2):

Make the newly created `.ndf` file as default data file. Like below :

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
MODIFY FILEGROUP Test1FG1 DEFAULT;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT;
GO
```

Comment: I made the recently created .NDF file as primary filegroup and as a default. I'm trying to add a new field of INT datatype with NULL via TSQL designer, its been since half an hour and not yet saved eventually SQL server raise error as NOT Responding . Any advice please ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by setting the `MAXSIZE` proprerty of the MDF file equal to current size:

```
ALTER DATABASE [yourDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'yourDB_mdf', SIZE = 500MB , MAXSIZE = 500MB )
```

In this case, **all new data pages** will be allocated and written to a new NDF. The second data file, of course, should have no `MAXSIZE` restrictions.

---

However, there is no easy way to rebalance existing data.
One of the approaches is:

- create a new FILEGROUP with multiple files
- rebuild indexes using `CREATE INDEX … WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)` plus specifying the new filegroup
- Shrink or delete the old filegroup to reclaim disk space.

Another approach is: [Split a file group into multiple data files](http://seekwellandprosper.com/2017/02/split-a-file-group-into-multiple-data-files/)