# Detach Secondary File Group from tables

Tags: sql-server

i'm using mssql for our database.
somehow previous developer before me was set up some table connected to secondary file group instead of the primary file group.

is there any way for us to make it stop string into the secondary file group and insert into primary file group.

because when we have a consultation with a DBA and found out it's not suitable.

Comment: Curious to know what the reason is that it's not suitable.  The fact that the dba didn't tell you how to do it makes me somewhat suspicious...

Comment: Your consultant told you not to use a secondary filegroup but offered no advice on how to solve the problem? That's pretty awful. Have you considered getting a second opinion?

Comment: can be done. First, specify what is the problem of your consultant with file group? This work is suitable to increase performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to change the table's filegroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928315/efficient-way-to-change-the-tables-filegroup)

Comment: A good consultant or dba should have explained the reason behind the suggestion. There are valid reasons to use secondary filegroups. TBH I doubt that the secondary FG has any significant impact on the general performance of your database. If no one is complaining about performance, then I would leave it as is unless you want to remove it for simplicity. If you do this, try it in a test environment first.